# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source' On my code

Tags: database, model-view-controller, datatables, argumentnullexception

I  tended to copy this code from a tutorial and fix it on my database tables however i keep on getting a thrown exception which is the one mentioned above..

i tried adding data source, didnt work.

Here's my Controller method:

```
     public ActionResult LoadData2()
    {
        try
        {
            //Creating instance of DatabaseContext class  
            using (AlwaysEmployedEntities _context = new AlwaysEmployedEntities())
            {
                var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
                var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
                var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
                var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
                var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();
                var searchValue = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]").FirstOrDefault();


                //Paging Size (10,20,50,100)    
                int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
                int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
                int recordsTotal = 0;

                // Getting all Customer data    
                var customerData = (from tempcustomer in _context.AspNetUsers
                                    select tempcustomer);

                //Sorting    
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
                {
                    customerData = customerData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
                }
                //Search    
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
                {
                    customerData = customerData.Where(m => m.UserName == searchValue );
                }

                //total number of rows count     
                recordsTotal = customerData.Count();
                //Paging     
                var data = customerData.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                //Returning Json Data    
                return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data });
            }
        }
catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

And here's my View:

```
    @{
    Layout = null;
    var id = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
    }

   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Browse Users</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myTable").DataTable({

            "processing": false, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "filter": false, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": true, // for disable multiple column at once
            "pageLength": 10,

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Browse/LoadData2",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },

            "columns": [
                { "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "UserName", "name": "UserName", "autoWidth": true }


            ]

        });
    });
</script>
<link href="/HackIt/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
    #header {
        padding: 10px 0;
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        z-index: 997;
    }

    body {
        background-image: url('/Login_v3/images/about2.jpeg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif, Verdana, Tahoma;
    }

    label {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 700;
    }


    .table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > td {
        padding: 8px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-top: 3px solid #ddd;
    }

    @@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
            transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    .zoomIn {
        -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
        animation-name: zoomIn;
    }

    @@keyframes zoomIn {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
            transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @@media only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 1030px) {
        .container {
            margin-top: 20%;
        }
    }

    table.dataTable tbody tr {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }

    .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td, .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }

    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:hover, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:active {
        cursor: default;
        color: black !important;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        background: transparent;
        box-shadow: none;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    @@media only screen and (min-width: 1030px) {
        .container {
            margin-top: 5%;
        }
    }

    #myTable_info {
        color: black;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    th {
        width: 200px;
    }

    tbody {
        color: aliceblue;
    }
</style>
 </head><body style="margin:20px auto">
          <main id="main">
           <header id="header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="logo" class="pull-left">
                <h1><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = id 
                })" class="scrollto" style="text-decoration:none;font-size:25px;"></a></h1>     
            </div>
            </div>
    </header>
     </main>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row heade/r">
        <center>
        <h2>Emp</h2>
        </center>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Browse", "Browse", new { id = id })"></a>
            </div>
             <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped"">
             <thead>
               <tr>
            <th><center>Id</center></th>
            <th><center>UserName</center></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

I cant relate whats the data source issue or the problem.. my model is functioning normally on other pages..
Any help would be appreciated.. thanks
Any help would be appreciated , thanks!

Comment: Where is the error being thrown?

Comment: I just edited my posted code, I missed the catch part in my controller method.. this part is throwing the Value cannot be null, parameter name: source error

Comment: The catch is throwing the error????

Comment: Yes the catch part